# android device compatibility

Tags: android

i don't know it is right place to ask question in stackoverflow .but i fell its best place to get quick answer for my query.
for getting more downloads i developed my application in android 1.5 version,minSDK 3. if i place application into android market.it will visible 1.5 and higher version mobile android market.it is good way for develop application in 1.5.how to make application good ui for all screen resolution

Thanks in Advance

Aswan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what your question is. But if you are asking if you develop your app against android 1.5, and you put it on the market, will everyone with 1.5+ see your app?

Yes, but just because it works on 1.5 doesn't mean it will work correctly on 1.6 or even 2.x. For example, one of my apps works in 1.5, 1.6, 2.0, 2.1 but stopped working correctly in 2.2 (froyo). So make sure you at least make sure it works in the emulator for each version. That will not give you 100% result if it will work on all devices, but it will be a start.

Comment: Thankq very much.if i develop application in android 1.6.how to make that to work on android 1.5 is there any way